# Can't register the app with the Google cloud platform

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-platform, oauth, google-oauth

I tried to register an application in the Googlt Cloud Platform They ask me to enter a home site and a link to the privacy policy because I do not have my own site, I entered my telegram channel into the window of the home site, and threw the privacy policy on google drive

And I got the problem shown in the picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtvLi.jpg

Comment: The solution is to set up your own domain and website.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is not because you have added google as the privacy policy, that is perfectly fine. The error you are getting is requiring you to add the domains added in the previous steps by clicking `Add Domain`.

Simply click the blue button in your screenshot, then add `google.com`. If you do not have a website, you do not need one right now. I would not add the `t.me` unless that is actually your website's domain. If you want to add it, follow similar steps to the previous domain and enter it in the field box as `t.me`. If you do not wish to use this, then remove it from the previous step and leave it blank for now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already did this, but then I received a letter in which I was asked to prove the rights to the domain
https://i.imgur.com/NB9Q4pd.png

Comment: Do you need the `t.me` domain? I believe keeping `google.com` is fine, but it is requiring you to verify your association with the other domain. I was fine with just linking the Google privacy policy and the store page. I left all other domain fields blank. I am also unsure of what fields you have typed in exactly, but I would use [this](https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en-US) link for the privacy policy and leave your ToS blank for now.